# How to make canvas particles follow mouse with JS?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I want to make the particles follow the mouse and I am not sure on how to do that.

I figured I can replace the x and y with the mouses position but I can figure that out either.

I would appreciate an almost exact answer and not examples please.

```js
window.onload = function() {
  var canvas = document.createElement("canvas"),
    c = canvas.getContext("2d"),
    particles = {}
  particleIndex = 0,
    particleNum = Math.random() * 2;


  canvas.width = 400;
  canvas.height = 400;

  document.body.appendChild(canvas);

  c.fillStyle = "black";
  c.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

  function Particle() {
    this.x = canvas.width / 10;
    this.y = canvas.height / 2;

    this.vx = Math.random() * 10 - 5;
    this.vy = Math.random() * 10 - 5;

    this.gravity = .2;

    particleIndex++;
    particles[particleIndex] = this;

    this.id = particleIndex;

    this.life = 0;
    this.maxLife = Math.random() * 30 + 10;

    this.color = "rgb(" + parseInt(Math.random() * 255, 10) + ",0,0)";
    this.color2 = "hsl(" + parseInt(Math.random() * 255, 10) + ",50%,50%)";
  }

  Particle.prototype.draw = function() {
    this.x += this.vx;
    this.y += this.vy;

    if (Math.random() < 0.1) {
      this.vx = Math.random() * 10 - 5;
      this.vy = Math.random() * 10 - 5;
    }
    this.vy += this.gravity;
    this.life++;

    if (this.Life >= this.maxLife) {
      delete particles[this.id];
    }

    c.fillStyle = this.color2;
    c.fillRect(this.x, this.y, 10, 10);

  };


  //var p = new Particle();

  setInterval(function() {
    c.fillStyle = "rgba(0,0,0,0.5)";
    c.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    for (var i in particles) {
      particles[i].draw();
    }
    for (var i = 0; i < particleNum; i++) {
      new Particle();
    }
  }, 30);

};
```

Comment: Here's a [previous post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28390481/js-canvas-animate-grid-elements-individually/28391058#28391058) showing how to repel particles on mousedown and restitute the particles on mouseup. You can modify that code to do your "follow the mouse" design.

Comment: I want it to follow the position of the mouse though.

Comment: Understood, you want to attract particles instead of repel them. The post shows how to repel when the particle is within the radius of influence of the mouse position. The process of attraction is the same -- except reversed. ;-)

Comment: Ok, Im starting to understand.  Do I have to click to find the mouse position?  Because I want it to automatically follow the mouse when the page loads.  Im sorry, that im not understanding this well.

Comment: Sure. :-) You can trigger the realignment on mousemove instead of mousedown. Yep, you will have to track the mouse position using the event object passed into your mousemove handler. It's way after midnight here so I'm too tired to do a demo tonight, but give it a try and I'll check back on this Q&A tomorrow. G'night!