# Drawing with sugar

Tags: javascript, jquery, canvas

I want to create a drawing in sugar thing, much the same as you would throw some sugar on a table and using your fingers to "erase" the sugar particles to form an image.

Does anyone know of a js type tool I can use to make this happen?

I suppose I can take a photo of a desk, and a photo of desk with some sugar on it, and then just erase the top layer, but I'm worried that this won't give a real effect.

I'm currently thinking of having a photo of desk, and then using JS to generate a lot of "sugary" particles, which I can then erase. This sounds incredibly hard to do though. Is it? Can someone point me in a good direction?

Comment: No need to reinvent the wheel ;) http://vincentgarreau.com/particles.js/

Comment: if you combine your basic approach with some shadowBlur while drawing on your canvas, you could get a more real effect

Comment: Interesting idea -- drawing with sugar. Check out this [Q&A](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28390481/js-canvas-animate-grid-elements-individually/28391058#28391058) that shows how to repel objects away from the mouse. It may give you some hints at creating your sugar art. :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Sand or is it sugar?

An interesting problem that I had to give a little time.

This works by creating several buffers to hold grains of sand (sugar) and give them life when they need to move.

There is no way that Javascript could do a whole screen of a million plus grains so this demo cheats by only updating a very few and prioritising for new movement rather than allow older moving grains to hog CPU time.

The arrays `active`, `sandStatus`, holds the sand gains. `active` has the pixel address as a 32Bit int and `sandStatus` has age. The Array `sand` holds the amount of sand at each pixel and is used to calculate the shadow effect (shadow could be much better using a webGL shader) and to work out which direction sand should slide if disturbed or dropped to the surface.

the var `activeMax` holds the max number of active sand grains. Increase for a better effect, decrease if the sim runs to slow.

To drop sand use the right mouse button. Hold at one spot to make a pile. Left button pushes the sand about. When you hit a bigger pile the machine may lag (depending on CPU power and browser (best in firefox)).

The `push` function checks the sand array for any sand. If found it pushes the sand away from the center and piles it up around the edge. Some sand will fall back.

The function `sprinkle` adds grains of sand (one are a time by pixel coordinate or by index). The function `push` does the sand drawing FX. `update` moves the sand grains by checking surrounding pixels heights and moving grains down hill. `renderPix` handles rendering grains, creating the shadows and deactivating sand grains. The Array `shadowChange` holds the index of pixels that have had changes so that the shadows can be updated.

Bottom half of the demo is just boilerplate for mouse and canvas setup. All the code in regard to the answer is in the first half.

```js
"use strict";

var activeMax = 2280;  // this is the number of sand grains that are processed at
                   // at time. Increase for better looking effect. decrease
                   // if the machine is not keeping up with the load

var cw;
var ch;
var w;  //  
var h;
var canvasBuf = document.createElement("canvas");
var ctxB
var globalTime;  // global to this 
var pixels
var sand;
var sandToFall;
var sandToFallCount = 36000;
var shadow; // shadow pixels
var activeMax = 2280;
var active; // index of pixel for active grain
var sandStatus; // status of active grain
var shadowChange; // holds index of pixels that have a shadow change
var pixels;
var buf;
var grain = 0xFFFFFFFF;
var shadowGrain = 0x00000000;
var ready = false;
var sandReady = 0;
var nextActive = 0;
var nextActiveShadow = 0;

var onResize = function(){
cw = canvas.width;
ch = canvas.height;
w = cw;  //  
h = ch;
pixels = w*h;
canvasBuf.width = w;
canvasBuf.height = h;
ctxB = canvasBuf.getContext("2d");
sand = new Uint8ClampedArray(pixels);
shadow = new Uint8ClampedArray(pixels); // shadow pixels
sandToFall = new Uint32Array(sandToFallCount);
activeMax = 2280;
active = new Uint32Array(activeMax); // index of pixel for active grain
sandStatus = new Uint16Array(activeMax); // status of active grain
shadowChange= new Uint32Array(activeMax); // holds index of pixels that have a shadow change
sandStatus.fill(0); // clear
active.fill(0);
shadowChange.fill(0);
ctxB.clearRect(0,0,w,h);
ctxB.fillStyle = "white";
ctxB.font = "84px arial";
ctxB.textAlign = "center";
ctxB.globalAlpha = 0.01;
for(var i = 0; i < 12; i ++){
    ctxB.fillText("Sand Doodler!",w/2 + (Math.random()-0.5)*5,h/2 + (Math.random()-0.5)*5);
}
ctxB.globalAlpha = 1;
pixels = ctxB.getImageData(0,0,w,h);
buf = new Uint32Array(pixels.data.buffer);   
for(i = 0; i < buf.length; i += 3){
    if(buf[i] !== 0){
        var c = buf[i] >>> 24;
        buf[i] = 0;
        while(c > 0){
            var ind = Math.floor(Math.random()*sandToFallCount);
            if(sandToFall[ind] === 0){
                sandToFall[ind] = i;
            }
            c = c >>> 1;
        }
    }
}
buf.fill(0);
offsets = [1,w-1,w,w+1,-w-1,-w,-w+1,-1];
shadowOffsets = [-w-1,-w,-1];
ready = true;
sandReady=0;
}
function sprinkle(x,y){
var ind;
if(y === undefined){
    ind = x;
}else{
    ind = x + y*w;
}
var alreadyExists = active.indexOf(ind);
var ac = nextActive;
if(alreadyExists > -1){
    sand[ind] += 1;
    shadow[ind] = 0; 
    sandStatus[alreadyExists] = 66;
}else{
    active[nextActive] = ind;
    sandStatus[nextActive] = 66;
    shadowChange[nextActiveShadow];
    nextActiveShadow = (nextActiveShadow+1)%activeMax;
    nextActive = (nextActive +1)%activeMax;
    sand[ind] += 1;
    shadow[ind] = 0;
}
return ac;
}

var offsets = [1,w-1,w,w+1,-w-1,-w,-w+1,-1];
var offsetCount = 8;
function update(){
var min,max,minDir,maxDir,dir,start,jj,j,ind,level,i,l1;
for( i = 0; i <activeMax; i ++){
    if(sandStatus[i] !== 0){
        ind = active[i];
        level = sand[ind];
        if(level === 1){
            sandStatus[i] = 1; // deactive is cant move (level ground)
        }else{
            min = level;
            var d;
            minDir = offsets[Math.floor(Math.random()*16)];
            dir = null;
            start = Math.floor(Math.random()*16); // start at a random direction
            for(j=0;j < offsetCount; j++){
                jj = offsets[(j + start)%offsetCount];
                l1 = sand[ind+jj];
                if(l1 < min){
                    min = l1;
                    minDir = jj;
                    d = (j + start)%offsetCount;
                }
            }
            dir = null;
            if(min >= level - 1){ // nowhere to move
                sandStatus[i] = 1;
                
            }else
            if(min < level-1){ // move to lowest
                dir = minDir
            }
            if(dir !== null){
                var lv = level-min;
                while(lv > 2){
                    active[i] = ind + dir;
                    if(sand[ind] > 1){
                        sand[ind] -= 2;
                        sprinkle(ind)
                    }else{
                        sand[ind] -=1;
                    }
                    ind = ind+dir;
                    sand[active[i]] += 1;
                    if(sand[active[i] + offsets[d]] >=level){
                        d+= Math.random()<0.5? 1 : offsetCount -1;
                        d %=offsetCount;
                    }
                    lv -= 1;
                }
                if(sand[ind]>0){
                    active[i] = ind + dir;
                    sand[ind] -= 1;
                }
                sand[active[i]] += 1;
            }
        }
    }
}   
}
var shadowOffsets = [-w-1,-w,-1];
var shadowCols = [0xFFf0f0f0,0xFFd0d0d0,0xFFb0b0b0,0xFF909090];
var shadowDist = [0xf0000000,0xd0000000,0xb0000000,0x90000000]; // shadow col no sand

// renders grains and adds shadows. Deactivates gains when they are done
function renderPix(){
var ac = 0;
for(var i = 0; i < activeMax; i ++){
    if(sandStatus[i] !== 0){
        ac += 1;
        var ind = active[i];
        buf[ind] = grain;
    }
}
for(var i = 0; i < activeMax; i ++){
    if(sandStatus[i] !== 0){
        var ind = active[i];
        var level = sand[ind];
        var col =0;
        if(sand[ind + shadowOffsets[0]] > level ){
            col = 2;
        }else
        if(sand[ind + shadowOffsets[1]] > level ){
            col =1;
        }else
        if(sand[ind + shadowOffsets[2]] > level ){
            col = 1;
        }
        buf[ind] = grain;  // add a sand grain to the image
        shadow[ind] = col;
        shadowChange[nextActiveShadow] = ind;
        nextActiveShadow = (nextActiveShadow + 1)%activeMax;

        var c = 4;
        while(c > 0){
            c-=1;
            ind += w + 1;
            var s = sand[ind];
            var dif = level - s;
            if(dif > 0){
                c-= dif;
            }
            shadow[ind] += 1;
            shadowChange[nextActiveShadow] = ind;
            nextActiveShadow = (nextActiveShadow + 1)%activeMax;
        }
        sandStatus[i] -= 1;
        if(sandStatus[i] === 1){
            sandStatus[i] = 0;
            active[i] = 0;                
        }
    }
}
// add calculated shadows
for(var i = 0; i < activeMax; i ++){
    if(shadowChange[i] !== 0){
        var ind = shadowChange[i];
        var s = shadow[ind] <4 ? shadow[ind]-1:3;
        if(sand[ind] > 0){
            buf[ind]=shadowCols[s];
        }else{
            buf[ind]=shadowDist[s];
        }
        shadowChange[i] = 0;
    }
}
   
}

// push sand about
function push(x,y,radius){
var iyy,iny
var rr = radius * radius ; 
x = Math.floor(x);
y = Math.floor(y);
for(var iy = -radius + 1; iy < radius; iy ++){
    iyy = iy * iy;
    iny = (y+iy) * w;
    for(var ix = -radius + 1; ix < radius; ix ++){
        if(ix*ix + iyy <= rr){ // is inside radius
            var ind = (x + ix) + iny; 
            if(sand[ind] > 0){
                var dir = Math.random() * Math.PI * 2;
                dir = Math.atan2(iy,ix)
                var r = radius + Math.random() * radius *0.2
                var xx = Math.cos(dir) * r;
                var yy = Math.sin(dir) * r;
                buf[ind] = 0x000000;
                sand[ind] = 0;
              
               ind = Math.floor(xx + x) + Math.floor(yy + y) * w;
               sprinkle(ind);
            }else{
                buf[ind] = 0;
            }
        }
    }
}
}

function showHeight(){  // for debugging only
for(var i = 0; i < sand.length; i ++){
    buf[i] = 0xff000000;
    var k = sand[i];
    buf[i] +=(k <<16) + (k<<8) + (k);
}
}

// main update function
function display(){
if(!ready){  // only when ready
    return;
}
//ctx.setTransform(1,0,0,1,0,0); // reset transform
ctx.clearRect(0,0,cw,ch);
var mx = Math.floor((mouse.x/cw)*w); // canvas buf mouse pos
var my = Math.floor((mouse.y/ch)*h);

// drop sand
if(mouse.buttonRaw & 4){
    for(var i = 0; i < 120; i ++){
        var dir = Math.random()*Math.PI;
        var dist = ((Math.random()+Math.random()+Math.random())/3-0.5) * 62;
        var x = Math.cos(dir) * dist;
        var y = Math.sin(dir) * dist;
        x += mx;
        y += my;
        x = Math.floor(x); // floor
        y = Math.floor(y); // floor
       
        sprinkle(x,y);
    }
}else{
    // drop sand for intro FX
    if(sandReady <sandToFallCount){
        for(var i = 0; i < 120; i ++){        
            if(sandToFall[sandReady] !== 0){
                sprinkle(sandToFall[sandReady] + offsets[Math.floor(Math.random()*8)%offsets.length]);
            }
            sandReady += 1;
        }
    }
}
   // push sand about.
   if(mouse.buttonRaw & 1){
   push(((mouse.x/cw)*w),((mouse.y/ch)*h),32); // scale mouse to canvasBuf size
}
update();
renderPix();
//showHeight();
ctxB.putImageData(pixels,0,0);
ctx.drawImage(canvasBuf,0,0,cw,ch);

}








//==================================================================================================
// The following code is support code that provides me with a standard interface to various forums.
// It provides a mouse interface, a full screen canvas, and some global often used variable 
// like canvas, ctx, mouse, w, h (width and height), globalTime
// This code is not intended to be part of the answer unless specified and has been formated to reduce
// display size. It should not be used as an example of how to write a canvas interface.
// By Blindman67
const U = undefined;const RESIZE_DEBOUNCE_TIME = 100;
var canvas,ctx,mouse,createCanvas,resizeCanvas,setGlobals,globalTime=0,resizeCount = 0; 

createCanvas = function () { var c,cs; cs = (c = document.createElement("canvas")).style; cs.position = "absolute"; cs.top = cs.left = "0px"; cs.zIndex = 1000; document.body.appendChild(c); return c;}
resizeCanvas = function () {
if (canvas === U) { canvas = createCanvas(); } canvas.width = window.innerWidth; canvas.height = window.innerHeight; ctx = canvas.getContext("2d"); 
if (typeof setGlobals === "function") { setGlobals(); } if (typeof onResize === "function"){ resizeCount += 1; setTimeout(debounceResize,RESIZE_DEBOUNCE_TIME);}
}
function debounceResize(){ resizeCount -= 1; if(resizeCount <= 0){ onResize();}}
setGlobals = function(){ cw = w = canvas.width; ch = h = canvas.height; mouse.updateBounds(); }
mouse = (function(){
function preventDefault(e) { e.preventDefault(); }
var mouse = {
    x : 0, y : 0, w : 0, alt : false, shift : false, ctrl : false, buttonRaw : 0, over : false, bm : [1, 2, 4, 6, 5, 3], 
    active : false,bounds : null, crashRecover : null, mouseEvents : "mousemove,mousedown,mouseup,mouseout,mouseover,mousewheel,DOMMouseScroll".split(",")
};
var m = mouse;
function mouseMove(e) {
    var t = e.type;
    m.x = e.clientX - m.bounds.left; m.y = e.clientY - m.bounds.top;
    m.alt = e.altKey; m.shift = e.shiftKey; m.ctrl = e.ctrlKey;
    if (t === "mousedown") { m.buttonRaw |= m.bm[e.which-1]; }  
    else if (t === "mouseup") { m.buttonRaw &= m.bm[e.which + 2]; }
    else if (t === "mouseout") { m.buttonRaw = 0; m.over = false; }
    else if (t === "mouseover") { m.over = true; }
    else if (t === "mousewheel") { m.w = e.wheelDelta; }
    else if (t === "DOMMouseScroll") { m.w = -e.detail; }
    if (m.callbacks) { m.callbacks.forEach(c => c(e)); }
    if((m.buttonRaw & 2) && m.crashRecover !== null){ if(typeof m.crashRecover === "function"){ setTimeout(m.crashRecover,0);}}        
    e.preventDefault();
}
m.updateBounds = function(){
    if(m.active){
        m.bounds = m.element.getBoundingClientRect();
    }
    
}
m.addCallback = function (callback) {
    if (typeof callback === "function") {
        if (m.callbacks === U) { m.callbacks = [callback]; }
        else { m.callbacks.push(callback); }
    } else { throw new TypeError("mouse.addCallback argument must be a function"); }
}
m.start = function (element, blockContextMenu) {
    if (m.element !== U) { m.removeMouse(); }        
    m.element = element === U ? document : element;
    m.blockContextMenu = blockContextMenu === U ? false : blockContextMenu;
    m.mouseEvents.forEach( n => { m.element.addEventListener(n, mouseMove); } );
    if (m.blockContextMenu === true) { m.element.addEventListener("contextmenu", preventDefault, false); }
    m.active = true;
    m.updateBounds();
}
m.remove = function () {
    if (m.element !== U) {
        m.mouseEvents.forEach(n => { m.element.removeEventListener(n, mouseMove); } );
        if (m.contextMenuBlocked === true) { m.element.removeEventListener("contextmenu", preventDefault);}
        m.element = m.callbacks = m.contextMenuBlocked = U;
        m.active = false;
    }
}
return mouse;
})();
function main(timer){ // Main update loop
globalTime = timer;
display();  // call demo code
requestAnimationFrame(main);
}
resizeCanvas(); 
mouse.start(canvas,true); 
window.addEventListener("resize",resizeCanvas); 
requestAnimationFrame(main);
```

```css
body {
  background:#49D;
}
.help {
  text-align : center;
  font-family : Arial,"Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,sans-serif;
  font-size : 18px;
}
```

```html
<div class="help">Right mouse to drop sand, left button to push it around.</div>
```

Comment: This is absolutely amazing!