# How could I make an optimized canvas pixel rendering?

Tags: javascript, canvas

I'm researching for a method for drawing a pixel with a well optimised method, 
reducing the probability of fps drops. I use 2d, because it's more easy than webgl contexts. Here is a code that I tried:

```
<script>
document.write(".")
document.body.innerHTML=""
document.body.style.margin="0 0 0 0"
c=document.createElement("canvas")
document.body.appendChild(c)
ctx=c.getContext("2d")
setInterval(function(){
c.width=innerWidth
c.height=innerHeight
for(x=0;x<innerWidth;x++){
for(y=0;y<innerHeight;y++){
ctx.fillStyle="rgba(0,0,0,1)"
ctx.fillRect(x,y,x+1,y+1)
}}},1)
</script>
```

But when I save this as html file and open the html file with a navigator, the navigator gets caught and takes more than 2 seconds for load an image.

Comment: Well your code is just `ctx.fillStyle = 'black'; ctx.fillRect(0,0,c.width,c.height)`. But I guess you want something more. If e.g, you need each pixel to have an different value, then work directly from an imageData, that you'll `put`on your context : `var data = ctx.createImageData(width, height);` then iterate through all pixels data ([r,g,b,a,r,g,b,a...]) or even use an Uint32Array, and finally `ctx.putImageData(data, x, y);`

Comment: This happens because **setInterval is blocking the browser to render**. You have to use **requestAnimationFrame**

Comment: @Kaiido
Yes, I want a pixel rendering context, which renders the pixels as I like, listening conditionals and variables.

Comment: @mariodiniz
How? I tried to use that and the browser doesn't draw the pixels...

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/mj71mscs/

Comment: @Kaiido
Yes, in a 320x320 px canvas run fast, but when I expand it, the navigator crashes into a memory.

Answer (score 0):

```
(() => { 
    document.write(".")
    document.body.innerHTML=""
    document.body.style.margin="0 0 0 0"
    c=document.createElement("canvas")
    document.body.appendChild(c)
    ctx=c.getContext("2d")
    c.width=innerWidth
    c.height=innerHeight
    x = 0;
    y = 0;

    function drawPixel() {

        ctx.fillStyle="rgba(0,0,0,1)";
        ctx.fillRect(x,y,x+1,y+1);
        x ++;
        if (x > innerWidth) {
            x = 0;
            y ++;
        }
        if (y < innerHeight)
            requestAnimationFrame(drawPixel);
    }

    requestAnimationFrame(drawPixel)
})()
```

Try this, it's almost the same you did. **You need to change some parts to get a better perfomance**, i just adapted your code to work with requestAnimationFrame.

Comment: why `(() => { ... })()`?

Answer (score 0):

The quickest way to draw pixels one at a time is to create a image data object and add a typed array that holds each pixel as a 32 bit integer.

```
// assuming the ctx has been defined
var pixelData = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, ctx.canvas.width, ctx.canvas.height);    
pixelData.data32 = new Uint32Array(pixelData.data.buffer); // create 32bit pixel
```

The quickest way to fill the buffered pixel data is via the `typedArray.fill` function

```
 const white = 0xFFFFFFFF;
 pixelData.data32.fill(white);
```

Or green

```
 const green = 0xFF00FF00;
 pixelData.data32.fill(green);
```

To set on pixel via its coordinates

```
  function setPixel(x,y,color){
       pixelData.data32[x + y * ctx.canvas.width] = color; 
  }
  setPixel(10,10,0xFFFFFFFF);
```

To move the pixels to the canvas use

```
 ctx.putImageData(pixelData,0,0);
```

The colour channels for a 32bit pixels are in the order ABGR such that `0xFF000000` is black `0x00000000` is transparent, `0xFFFF0000` is blue, `0xFF00FF00` is green and `0xFF0000FF` is red. (note in some very rare situations the can change depending on the hardware's Endianness )

Comment: If you don't need to read the pixels, then don't use `getImageData` but `createImageData`. Also, an important point to include in an answer to this question is that `setInterval(f, 1)` with an heavy `f` is a call for crash. And I don't see the point of `ImageData.data.fill` when we've got `fillRect` already (except to avoid antialiasing if you draw at non rounded coords? Then just round your coords.)

Comment: @Kaiido `Fill` is a one dimensional function with 2 clipping boundaries and no compositing which on most machines will be performed by a blit and `fillRect` is two dimensional with 4 or more clipping boundaries using the current composite operation. There is no error in the code, just a logic/timing flaw. The question asked is clear, if you have a quicker way to set a random accessed pixels with a precise RGBA value let us know. And I am sure the OP knows the difference between get and create though do tell why you should not use `getImageData`

Comment: Hum what ? your `Fill` is not just `Array.fill`, it's `Array.flll` + `putImageData` I guess the complexity of `putImageData` depends on every implementations, but I am sure it's not a one dimensional function at all. https://jsperf.com/imagedata-fill-vs-fillrect/ Also, I am pretty sure it's the first time OP heard about ImageData, so there is little chances that he knows the difference between create and get, which in terms of perfs is also huge (one avoids the reading + unmultiplying of all data https://jsperf.com/createimagedata-vs-getimagedata/1

Comment: And even just fillRect vs array.fill (e.g to set an background and then some unique pixels) takes about the same time on my machine (fillRect is a bit faster in my FF) https://jsperf.com/fill-vs-partial-imagedata-fillrect/1

Comment: Consider a function `setPixels(pixels)` where pixels is and array of `{x,y,ABGR}` where `ABGR` is a int32 and `x`,`y` are random pixel coords. For small size pixels array and large image size you would use direct rendering, for all other cases you would write directly to the imageData. The OP shows the equivalent to the pixels array equal to image pixel count, Directly writing to pixel data becomes efficient some where under 1 as in `1 > (optimal = pixels.length / (Image.width * image.height))` and that unknown value `optimal` is smaller for smaller images. As the problem is unbound the set of

Comment: @Kaiido continues from above comment.  ...values above optimal is far greater than the set below and hence the quickest way to write pixels as inferred by the OP's question is how I have answered.

Comment: I am not questionning the use of the ImageData, if you read the first comment below the question, you'll see that it's what I already adviced to OP. My point is that 3/4 of your answer uses this fill method, which is an useless method. I also pointed out the difference between get and create imagedata which is important in this case.

Comment: Use get if you need pixel state, and/or you maintain pixel state i the array. You forget that canvas 2D API state changes required to set col, alpha clear or gCO all have overheads. I show the fill because I see loops used to set many array items to the same value a common mistake. I showed an example of directly writing to a type array and I did not show set as many will use `data.set([r,g,b,a],i)` rather than `data32[i] = RGBA`.  see this https://stackoverflow.com/a/39132481/3877726  and there are a few more where the only rendering solution is via the array as pixel rendering is too slow

Comment: @DarkGuy What part are you having problems with?

Comment: Ok, I now am using a better code. Thanks for helping. Should I create a new answer?

Comment: The worst trouble is that your method is only 8x faster. The screen is laggy with the `setPixel()` function...

Comment: @DarkGuy You should not use the function, That is just an example which defines the arguments. For high performance code you should keep as much as possible inline rather than call functions.

Comment: And... how to optimize fill.rect(0,0,c.width,c.height)?

Comment: @DarkGuy I assume you mean `ctx.fillRect(` for filling the canvas that call is the best you can get. The fill is performed by the GPU. You could get slightly better with WebGL but not much depending on how you set it up.

Comment: You can use `ClearColor(r,g,b,1)` and `clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT)` for drawing a color in the entire canvas. I'm sure that all pixel values changes when I execute clear(). The trouble resides editing the pixels' values.

Comment: DarkGuy If you are using WebGL then you have direct access to pixels via the GPU and a frame buffer

Comment: @DarkGuy there are any number of cloud based application platforms that provide scalable solutions for any type of processing job you can imagine. But remember that the result of processing is limited the client's bandwidth and ping time. You are essentially creating real time streaming media, if this is in response to user action there is network latency involved.

Comment: I'm now planning to send near 1 image per 20 miliseconds to the client. The image must be rendered, and I can do it via nodejs, there are some articles which speaks about `CanvasRenderer()` in threejs.

Comment: @DarkGuy  At  20ms is 50 a second, using node.js is not an effective solution for computationally demanding data in terms of cost, you would be far better of using a compiled language C++, Java, or the like at the server Your question does state no webGL, yet it is the best solution . One day when server costs come down all realtime content will be server generated, till then we pack high performance graphics cards into our devices to do the processing client side. I have yet to see any interactive full frame realtime content from the cloud, though I have not looked for it.

Comment: C++ and java are slow options. I suposse the most fast option is loading a .img or .iso file, but it's hard, because the server can't comunicate with the client.

Answer (score 0):

After more than 2 years, I made the correct answer to this question:

Library:
Name: jDrFrankCabezaMisilv45.js

```
//jDrFrankCabezaMisil.js
class $ {
  constructor(){
    this.c = document.createElement('canvas')
    document.body.style.margin = '0'
    document.body.style.overflow = 'hidden'
    this.c.style.width = '100vw'
    this.c.style.height = '100vh'
    this.c.width = 1920
    this.c.height = 960
    this.context = this.c.getContext("2d")
    this.imgData = this.context.createImageData(this.c.width, this.c.height)
    document.body.appendChild(this.c)
    this.Vector1 = class Vector1{
      constructor(x){
        let vec = {x:x}
        vec.distanceTo = function(vec2) {
          return Math.abs(this.x-vec2.x)
        };
        return vec
      }
    }
    this.Vector2 = class Vector2{
      constructor(x, y){
        let vec = {x:x, y:y}
        vec.distanceTo = function(vec2) {
          return ((this.x-vec2.x)**2+(this.y-vec2.y)**2)**0.5
        }
        return vec
      }
    }
    this.Vector3 = class Vector3{
      constructor(x, y, z){
        let vec = {x:x, y:y, z:z}
        vec.distanceTo = function(vec2) {
          return ((this.x-vec2.x)**2+(this.y-vec2.y)**2+(this.z-vec2.z)**2)**0.5
        }
        return vec
      }
    }
    this.Vector4 = class Vector4{
      constructor(x, y, z, a){
        let vec = {x:x, y:y, z:z, a:a}
        vec.distanceTo = function(vec2) {
          return ((this.x-vec2.x)**2+(this.y-vec2.y)**2+(this.z-vec2.z)**2+(this.a-vec2.a)**2)**0.5
        }
        return vec
      }
    }
    let rnd=_=>{
      return Math.random()
    }
    let sin=(x)=>{
      return Math.sin(x)
    }
    let cos=(x)=>{
      return Math.cos(x)
    }
    let toDegrees=(angle)=>{
      return angle * (180 / Math.PI);
    }
    let toRadians=(angle)=>{
      return angle * (Math.PI / 180);
    }
    this.time=0
    let colors=new this.Vector3("rnd()","rnd()","rnd()")
    this.update=_=>{
      let compute=`
        for (let i = 0; i < this.imgData.data.length; i += 4) {
          let x = i % (this.c.width*4);
          let y = i / (this.c.width*4) % (this.c.height*4);
          x/=this.c.width*4;
          y/=this.c.height;
          let t=this.time/10;
          this.imgData.data[i + 0] = (`+colors.x+`)*255;
          this.imgData.data[i + 1] = (`+colors.y+`)*255;
          this.imgData.data[i + 2] = (`+colors.z+`)*255;
          this.imgData.data[i + 3] = 255;
        }
      `
      this.time++
      requestAnimationFrame(this.update)
      this.c.width = innerWidth
      this.c.height = innerHeight
      this.imgData = this.context.createImageData(this.c.width, this.c.height)
      document.body.style.margin=0

      // Recorrer cada píxel de la imagen
      eval(compute)

      // Dibujar la imagen de datos en el canvas
      this.context.putImageData(this.imgData, 0, 0)
    }
    this.update()
    this.Epilepsia2d=class Epilepsia2d{
      constructor(vec3){
        colors=vec3
      }
    }
  }
}

export default new $()
```

This is the import test file:

```html
<script type="module">
import $ from './jDrFrankCabezaMisilv45.js'
</script>
```

And this is to modify the canvas:

```html
<script type="module">
import $ from './jDrFrankCabezaMisilv45.js'
new $.Epilepsia2d(new $.Vector3("1/2<y?1:0","1/2<x?1:0","1/2>x&&1/2>y?1:0"))
</script>
```